# NSDateFormatter DateFromString return nil

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I Know it may be got answered a lot here but i think i have a different case

I'm getting the string date in the following format

> 2014-04-14 16:04:07 +0000

And using the following code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *startDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:st];
```

But startDate always give me nil

Comment: The +000 isn't managed.

Comment: Look at your date string, then look at your format string. Figure out what describes what, for instance, 'HH' to hours. Then, tell me what's missing.

Comment: Your format string does not match your data.

Comment: You should bookmark the [date formatting codes](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle zone too. Correct variant:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
```

Also consider to use nice lib for date formatting [ISO8601DateFormatter](https://github.com/keithpitt/ISO8601DateFormatter). It will handle your format automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

If that format does not match the format of the date string *exactly*, the result of `dateFromString:` is nil.

It doesn't so it is.